# Exporting Datatable and Gridview data simultaneously to pdf and excel

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, c#-3.0

I have datatable which has single column and gridview 3 columns. On clicking this i need to display all 4. Is it possible to display? The datatable column can be below gridview columns also.

Answer (score 0):

aspx:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnExportToExcel" Text="Export TO Excel"

runat="server" OnClick="btnExportToExcel_OnClick" />
```

code:

```
     protected void btnExportToExcel_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {

    DataTable dtRiskFact = (DataTable)Session["dtRiskFact"];  //save datatable in session and get it 
    Response.Clear();
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Summary_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy") + ".xls");
    Response.Charset = "";
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls";
    System.IO.StringWriter StringWriter = new System.IO.StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter HtmlTextWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(StringWriter);

    GridView grdExprExcel = this.grdEditBranch;   //your grid
grdExprExcel.Columns[0].Visible=false         // hide columns like this
    grdExprExcel.AllowPaging = false;
    grdExprExcel.DataSource = dtRiskFact;
    grdExprExcel.DataBind();

    grdExprExcel.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter);
    Response.Write(StringWriter.ToString());

    Response.End();
}
```